# Used Heap grow from 150Mb to 2Gb in half a second

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

[image: heapLeap]

Hi guys, 
as you can see I Have a strange spike of used heap, that never return to the normal level. In the image, in 0.27 seconds the used heap grow from 100Mb to 706Mb. We tryed to give more memory to Tomcat, but the problem remain the same, except for the fact that now the used heap grow from 150Mb to 1.7Gb of memory.
We are monitoring the situation in ant way we know, but neither the memory monitor neither the various log give us a solution.
Have you a hint?

Thank You,
Marco

Comment: take a heapdump and see what is taking up the space....

Comment: we have 2 things, a String and a Char[] that occupy a lot of space, but how can I figure where they are instantiated?

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting out of memory errors? If not, this is a non issue. Many things utilize caching and will take up as much memory as you can give them to improve performance. So unless you are getting out of memory errors or GC thrashing, this is not something to be concerned about.

Comment: The problem is that we get some out-of-memory exception, and anyway, the GC stop to clean the memory (even if we send him a signal to do it).